# Pass through touch events to app beneath

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android Activity which should not be full screen and thus uses Dialog theme. This can be achieved by adding

```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to the activity definition in Manifest file.

Visually that does what I expect. However, when the user interacts with the device in an area outside of this activity, the app in the background does not receive this input.

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean to disable modality of the activity looking like dialog??? if that's what you want I don't think it's achievable with activities if I got the question right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible with your solution as there is only one Activity possible to be active. You could try that with Fragments but I doubt that you could open your App and navigate the Homescreen / whatever in the meantime.